# Round up to the nearest 0.05

Tags: python, math, rounding

I want to round up a number to 2 decimals, for example:

```
16.34 -> 16.35
16.36 -> 16.40
16.31 -> 16.35
16.35 -> 16.35 -- NOT ROUND
16.40 -> 16.40 -- NOT ROUND
```

If the number ended in 1-4 round to 5 and if the number 6-9 then round up to 0
How i can round up=
Thanks u

Comment: multiple by 20, round to integer, divide by 20

Comment: *Ceiling to integer

Comment: `import math; math.ceil(x * 20) / 20`.

Comment: @ThomasJager yes, thans for correction, I did not check correctly the requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the number by 20 (the reciprocal of 0.05), round up with [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil), and divide by the reciprocal.

For example:

```
>>> from math import ceil
>>> r = 0.05 ** -1
>>> for n in (i/100 for i in range(10, 20)):
...     m = ceil(n*r) / r
...     print('{:.2f} -> {:.2f}'.format(n, m))
...
0.10 -> 0.10
0.11 -> 0.15
0.12 -> 0.15
0.13 -> 0.15
0.14 -> 0.15
0.15 -> 0.15
0.16 -> 0.20
0.17 -> 0.20
0.18 -> 0.20
0.19 -> 0.20
```

*[Due credit to [Jan Stránský's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62998112/round-up-to-the-nearest-0-05/62998521#comment111404409_62998112) and [Thomas Jager's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62998112/round-up-to-the-nearest-0-05/62998521#comment111404826_62998112) comments for explaining the technique]*

Edit: Revisiting this, I think it's equivalent to a) use 0.05 itself instead of its reciprocal, reversing the operations, and b) use negative floor division instead of `ceil`.

```
>>> r = 0.05
>>> for n in (i/100 for i in range(10, 20)):
...     m = n // -r * -r
...     print('{:.2f} -> {:.2f}'.format(n, m))
...
```

(same output)